# The notation of 'greater than or equal to'.

Tags: notation, terminology

I've known that the following marks are equal.

[image]

However, both marks are used in the same book. I was wondering whether there is some difference between them.

Comment: No, they're the same.

Comment: @AlexG. Exactly same? I accepted they are same if 'A' book uses only left symbol, 'B' book uses only right symbol. However my book uses both symbols simultaneously. Is there any reason the book uses both symbols simultaneously.

Comment: In my experience, they always, always, always mean the same thing

Comment: @AlexG. Thank you. And sorry for casting doubt on your first answer.

Comment: Lack of good proofreading is the most likely explanation. Are there multiple authors? Let me guess... ;/